# Page transition not happening when I click on hyperlink with Geb

Tags: grails, groovy, spock, geb

When I use

```
searchResults(0).ApplicationId.click(ApplicationSummaryPage)
```

the transition happens to ApplicationSummaryPage but when I use this

```
searchResults(0).ApplicationId.click()
```

I doesn't see the page transition happening. I verified this by overriding the `onLoad` and `onUnload` methods. I however can visually verify (when Geb opens the browser during test run) that the control is transferring to ApplicationSummaryPage.

```
void onLoad(Page previousPage)
{
    println ("(ApplicationSummaryPage) previousPage = "+previousPage);
}

void onUnload(Page newPage)
{
    println ("(ApplicationSummaryPage) newPage = "+newPage);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran through the same issue you can solve this

1. By checking the url handler in Page Object
2. In static content where you declared for the click functionality add
   this code (to:ApplicationSummaryPage) and create method which return
   the browser page instance.

eg.,

```
class TestPage extends Page{
  static content = {
    clickBtn(to:ApplicationSummaryPage) { //logic goes here }
  }
  ApplicationSummaryPage onClickBtn()
  {
    clickBtn.click()
    browser.page
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to extend this solution in a case when there is a list of available pages in that clickBtn definition (I mean: to: [Page1, Page2, ..., PageN])?